# Blockquotes styling

Tags: discussion, design

Well, it appears they've been revamped (after some here mentioned they were a bit too subtle.) What do you guys think of them now? Too pronounced? Perhas the blue bar should be washed out a bit more...Either way, it's definitely an improvement over the almost-non-detectable-background from before.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

At first I thought there was something wrong with my computer, but now I actually like them because they actually bring out the quotes a lot better. I don't think it's the -best- idea, but it's a lot better than trying to guess where the quotes are.

Answer (score 4):

I like them.

I would like to see more difference between code and quotes (beyond code getting a fixed width font), though.

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather see them suspended in some sort of dark gray box, that is just too distracting for me right now.

Answer (score 0):

I would also like to see something similar here on Meta.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [TheTXI](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8446/su-blockquotes/8448#8448), I actually like the hard highlight, as on some LCDs the greyish is too subtle to be distinguished.

Comment: What is even up with your DisplayName?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25676/do-vba-question-belong-on-so-or-su/25682#25682

Comment: Upvoted that comment too and didn't even cotton on then.

Comment: @random: you've set adblock to block my name, haven't you?

Comment: Adblock? Isn't that a non-Opera thing?

Comment: Its a non `lynx` thing

Answer (score 0):

Maybe keep them for the quotes but remove them from code. It is way too distracting to be of any use.